# Given the code in tuple format, how to convert to dictionary format using listing

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following:

```py
TEST = (("g", ["g","h"]), ("i",["i","j"]), ("k",["k","l"]))
```

Based on TEST, I am trying to get to this format dictionary:

```py
{'g': 'h', 'i': 'j', 'k': 'l'}
```

I have tried using

```py
d = dict(TEST)
```

but this outputs a dict with a different format to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Your `list` structure contains `key` and `values`

- First you need to visualize key and values:

  - ```py
    for key, value in TEST:
        print(key)
        print(value)
    ```
  - Result:
  - ```py
    g
    ['g', 'h']
    i
    ['i', 'j']
    k
    ['k', 'l']
    ```
- You want the `key` and the last element of the `values`:

  - ```py
    for key, value in TEST:
        print(key)
        print(value[len(value)-1])
    ```
  - Result:

    ```py
    g
    h
    i
    j
    k
    l
    ```
- For each corresponding key, set the last item of the value

  - ```py
    d = {}

    for key, value in TEST:
        d[key] = value[len(value)-1]
    ```
  - Result:

    ```py
    {'g': 'h', 'i': 'j', 'k': 'l'}
    ```

If you are sure you want the second element in the `values` list, then:

```py
d = dict((key, value[1]) for key, value in TEST)
```

Result:

```py
{'g': 'h', 'i': 'j', 'k': 'l'}
```